# PHP output multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been stuck on this issue for a while now. I have a multidimensional array that I'd like to output in a certain way. Here is the array:

```
    array:3 [
      "First Name" => array:3 [
        0 => "BILLY"
        1 => "SALLY"
        2 => "TYLER"
      ]
      "Last Name" => array:3 [
        0 => "RAY"
        1 => "SUE"
        2 => "TERRIER"
      ]
      "HOBBY" => array:3 [
        0 => "PIANO"
        1 => "SKATING"
        2 => "BASKETBALL"
      ]
    ]
```

I'd like to have the final output be the following:

```
    BILLY|RAY|PIANO|
    SALLY|SUE|SKATING|
    TYLER|TERRIER|BASKETBALL|
```

Unfortunately with the existing code I have:

```
    $output = '';
     foreach($tempArray as $key => $value){
         $output .= $value[array_search($key,$tempArray)].$delimiter;  
     }
```

it only outputs the first index of each array like so:

```
    BILLY|RAY|PIANO|
```

So my question is how do I end up with the remaining two values? Should I create some sort or array and counter and and store each output this way: `$newArray[$counter] = $output`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `array_column()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) will fetch a column from a 2-dimensional array. Then just jam them all together.

```
$array = [
    "First Name" => ["BILLY", "SALLY", "TYLER"],
    "Last Name" => ["RAY", "SUE", "TERRIER"],
    "HOBBY" => ["PIANO", "SKATING", "BASKETBALL"],
];

$result = implode("|", array_column($array, 0)) . "\n";
$result .= implode("|", array_column($array, 1)) . "\n";
$result .= implode("|", array_column($array, 2));
echo $result;
```

As pointed out in a comment, you may not always know the length of the child arrays. That would mean wrapping this in a loop:

```
$iterations = count(reset($array));
$result = "";
for ($i = 0; $i <= $iterations; $i++) {
    $result .= implode("|", array_column($array, $i)) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If all three sub-arrays are always the same size, you could just use a for loop:

```
$array = [
    "First Name" => ["BILLY", "SALLY", "TYLER"],
    "Last Name" => ["RAY", "SUE", "TERRIER"],
    "HOBBY" => ["PIANO", "SKATING", "BASKETBALL"],
];

$result = '';
$size = count($array["First Name"]);
for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++){
   $result.= "{$array['First Name'][$i]}|{$array['Last Name'][$i]}|{$array['HOBBY'][$i]}\r\n";
}
echo $result;
```

[image]